# f:websocket stops working in JSF 2.3 after application redeployment on wildfly

Tags: jsf, websocket, wildfly

I'm developing a new application using websockets and decided to use JSF 2.3 in wildfly 15. All is working fine until I try to redeploy my code using wildfly management console. Websockets stops working after this point and I can just make it work after a server restart. I made a simple application to test this behaviour with this code in the body of xhtml:

```
<f:websocket channel="test" />
```

When the application is redeployed I noticed that my page keeps trying to make requests to websocket endpoint and keeps receiving multiple *101 (Switching protocols)* as response code in short intervals (about 5 requests/second).

[Firefox network inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqkjk.png)

I used wireshark to capture traffic and discovered that just after this response wildfly send a *websocket connection close [FIN]*.

I tried to narrow down this issue and seems to me like a wildfly bug. I used fresh installations of wildfly 15.0.1.Final and 16.0.0.Final. Does anyone have a workaround or a working solution for this?

Comment: Did you try doing the same on GlassFish? Maybe it is not WildFly related but Mojarra. Can you try what `o:omnifaces` does

Comment: I tested it yesterday on glassfish with a very simple application (just testing network websocket connection - to narrow down the problem as much as possible), and couldn't see the same behaviour I had on wildfly (repeated 101 responses), so I thought I couldn't reproduce on glassfish. After your comment I decided to make a more functional test application and realized websocket communication stops working after app reload on glassfish. So this should be related to https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4368, with just a different behavious when happening on wildfly.

Comment: Also I tried with omnifaces it works just fine after reload/redeploy

Comment: This is still happening on wildfly 21, just added a comment on the bug report. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Mojarra 2.3.15 (released May 2021).

It was initially already fixed at May 2019 for the imagined 2.3.10 version via [issue 4565](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4565) wherein I have backported the fixes from `<o:socket>` into `<f:websocket>`. Unfortunately it was done during the Oracle -> Eclipse transition and in hindsight the changes appear to have completely slipped through during the chaos. So it was re-done via [issue 4802](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4802) for 2.3.15.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a very simple application on glassfish (with just f:websocket on xhtml - no backing bean, just to test network websocket connection) and couldn't get the same result I had on wildfly (repeated 101 responses), so I thought this wouldn't apply in glassfish (thus unrelated to [Websocket PushContext not working anymore after application redeploy](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4368))

After reading [Kukeltje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4478047/kukeltje) comment I decided to make a more functional test application and noticed that websocket stopped working on glassfish after reload (but couldn't get multiple 101 responses - as in wildfly).

So this must be related to [Websocket PushContext not working anymore after application redeploy](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4368)

[Test application source](https://github.com/paulojjj/websocket)

[Test application WAR](https://www.dropbox.com/s/639u6mq5e0uekwx/websocket.war?dl=1)

Comment: Hi there, were you able to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I didn't have much time to investigate it further since I now have other priorites (this particular application is still waiting for approval). I just found an open ticket here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4572

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the source code. Omnifaces websocket implementation fixed the bug. I would recommend using that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).